# How to Replace Nan and Inf values with 0 in series of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I am making some calculations for series of data as well as variables and am getting some Nan values as well as Infl values.. I am trying to replace these with zeros

I have tried using .fillna(0), but does not seem to make any changes to the results..

Here is what my code is:

```
HWM_CntrMngFut = np.maximum.accumulate(data.ContrlMngFut_Return) #Compute High Water Marker 
 - the running maximum
DD_CntrMngFut = (HWM_CntrMngFut - data.ContrlMngFut_Return)/HWM_CntrMngFut #Drawdown

DD_CntrMngFut.fillna(0)

MDD_CntrMngFut = np.maximum.accumulate(DD_CntrMngFut) #Maximum Drawdown with control

print ("X is", data.X_MngFut )
print ("HWM is", HWM_CntrMngFut)
print ("DD is", DD_CntrMngFut)
print ("MDD is", MDD_CntrMngFut)


i_CntrMngFut = np.argmax(HWM_CntrMngFut - data.ContrlMngFut_Return)

print ("Maximum Drawdown for Managed Futures Without Control is %",MDD_MngFut[i_MngFut])
print ("Maximum Drawdown for Managed Futures With Control is 
 %",MDD_CntrMngFut[i_CntrMngFut])
```

Could someone please let me know how to replace all Nan and infl values with zero here?

Data output is coming out as:
      X is 0           NaN
      1      0.000000
2      0.000000
3     -0.583996
4     -0.663946
         ...
217   -0.370332
218   -0.671487
219   -0.432080
220   -0.355075
221   -0.899898
Name: X_MngFut, Length: 222, dtype: float64

HWM is 0      0.000000
1      0.000000
2      0.000000
3      0.000000
4      0.000000
         ...
217    0.094699
218    0.094699
219    0.094699
220    0.094699
221    0.094699
Name: ContrlMngFut_Return, Length: 222, dtype: float64

DD is 0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           inf
4           inf
         ...
217    1.047079
218    0.789772
219    1.019615
220    1.088973
221    0.661590
Name: ContrlMngFut_Return, Length: 222, dtype: float64

MDD is 0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
       ..
217   NaN
218   NaN
219   NaN
220   NaN
221   NaN

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you add some part of your dataset where you have Nan and infl values?

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour, especially [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SAIPRATYUSHA i have added some of the data with Nan and Infl values

Answer (score 0):

when you are using fillna(), it does not do inplace replacement.
so set the inplace parameter to True.

```
DD_CntrMngFut.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: it is giving me: NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: I made an edit . The boolean value True has a capital 'T'

Comment: Thank you this works, do you know how to replace the infl values also?

Comment: `DD_CntrMngFut[~np.isfinite(DD_CntrMngFut)] = 0`